# Megapixels at 100mm and 200mm

Tags: megapixels

If I take a photo at 100mm that fills the frame and take the same photo at 200mm will each photo have the same megapixels?

Comment: this question doesn't make sense. what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The real question is: why should megapixels change depending on the focal length?

Answer (score 3):

> If I take a photo at 100mm that fills the frame and take the same photo at 200mm will each photo have the same megapixels?

**Yes.** The image sensor in the camera is the same sensor, and it'll record the same number of pixels no matter what you point it at or what lens you put in front of it. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *take the same photo at 200mm* -- you could be staying in the same location and zooming, in which case you'll get an image that's like the center portion of the first image; or you could be moving back while zooming in, to get an image with a similar field of view but different perspective. Either way, if your camera recorded a 10 megapixel image with the first shot, and you don't change the camera's image size setting, then the second shot will also be a 10 megapixel image.

Comment: Thanks much. I mean if I take a photo of say a lion at 100mm that fills the frame and the same lion from  farther back where I need to zoom to 200mm is the megapixels the same

Comment: Yes, if the subject fills the frame the same way, and the rest of the image is roughly the same, the total megapixels will be roughly the same.

Comment: As long as he isn’t using digital zoom like on a phone.